# Time dependent equation fitting: Input is vector whereas output is scalar

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am new to python an d hope someone could help me here. I have this code i want to use for fitting of an experimental data:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pandas as pd
import sys
from scipy.optimize import minimize

fileID = open("testdata.txt", "r+")
(t,Ids_measured) = np.loadtxt(fileID,unpack =True)
try:
all_the_file = fileID.readlines()
finally:
fileID.close()


Ids_final = Ids_measured[-1]


Ids_m = ()

def model_Ids(x0):
    Amp = x0[0]
    ß = x0[1]
    tau = x0[2]
    for i in range(len(t)):
     Ids_m=(Ids_final - sum(Amp* (np.exp((-(t/ tau))))**ß))
    return Ids_m

def objective(x0):
    Ids_model = ()
    Ids_m = ()
    Ids_model =model_Ids(x0)

    obj = 0.0
    for i in range(len(Ids_measured)):
    obj = obj + ((Ids_m[i]-Ids_measured[i])/Ids_measured[i])**2   
    return obj 

    x0 = np.zeros(3)
    x0[0] = 0.0 # Amp
    x0[1] = 0.0 # ß
    x0[2] = 0.0 # tau
```

First, i want to load a text file and using a mathematical equation solve for Ids_m (modeling part). Since equation for Ids_m has some model variables, i want to change this later to match the objective defined in the objective function. The problem is when i run the code, i usually get a scalar for Ids_m instead of a vector for all values of t. Thus i have the error:

```
obj = obj + ((Ids_m[i]-Ids_measured[i])/Ids_measured[i])**2
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can someone help me point to the error in this line of code. I would like to have the function model_Ids(x0) return a vector with lenght equal to the lenght of t

Thanks.

Comment: After a quick look, it seems that `Ids_m` variable in `objective` function is initialized to an empty tuple (which is not very useful because tuples are immutable) and then used in your for loop over `len(Ids_measured)`, so it will always fail because you are trying to access something in an empty tuple. The problem does not come from the other function imo.

Comment: From what you appear to be trying to do, replace `Ids_m` with `Ids_model`in the line `obj = obj + ((Ids_m[i]-Ids_measured[i])/Ids_measured[i])**2`

Comment: Also you should be careful with your indentation, it seems it was not copied correctly when you copied your code in your question. Indentation is not just cosmetic in python as you might already know, it defines blocks of code and is part of the syntax.

Comment: Thanks @ValentinB. Following your advise make the code to run completely. Still it outputs a scalar variable. i would need it to output a value for each t imput. i have loaded the file as vector and can get each imput of t and Ids_measured. Is there something i am missing here?